# Change definition of unanswered questions answered by excluding those answered by self

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

When I go to the unanswered page of a tag, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?tab=Unanswered) my usual intent is to see if i can act so that it no longer is unanswered.

Outside of the unfortunate cases where i can only comment or flag, there are typically two actions to take:

1. Vote on an existing answer
2. Answer the question myself

HOWEVER, in the smaller tags I am running into the situation where I answer a few questions, and they remain on top of the unanswered list because nobody voted on them (yet).

I don't think these questions are very usefull to be shown *to me* under unanswered, hence I recommend them to be filtered out.

I know that I can use the advanced search to work around this, but am still **suggesting the filtering out of questions that are (only) answered by oneself** as these are typically not what I and presumably others look for when going to the unanswered tag.

---

I also realize this would change the unanswered view from a generic one to a personalized one, so if it is too complicated it does not need to be prioritized.

Comment: You can use `filters=NoAnswers` in the query string to only get questions with no answers at all if that fits your needs

Comment: That is interesting though I do want to vote on the questions that actually have answers. Also I think my suggestion to filter out self answered questions without extra effort would be something almost everyone would benefit from.